# How do I correctly type an array property iterator like this in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Take this example code:

```js
interface Cat {
  fur: string
  food: string
}

const cats: Array<Cat> = [
  {
    fur: 'brown',
    food: 'fish'
  },
  {
    fur: 'white',
    food: 'biscuits'
  }
];

interface Cols {
  name: string
  title: string
}

const cols: Array<Cols> = [
  {
    name: 'fur',
    title: 'Fur colour'
  },
  {
    name: 'food',
    title: 'Favourite food'
  }
];

cats.map(cat => {
  cols.map(col => {
    console.log(`${col.title} - ${cat[col.name]}`); // errors here
  });
});
```

It errors on `cat[col.name]` with:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Cat'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Cat'.(7053)
```

I can suppress that error by adding `any` to `cat` but that defeats the point. What's the correct way to type this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because TypeScript sees `col.name` as a string, and the `Cat` interface only contains two possible keys (not any string as keys). In theory, `col.name` can return *any* string that is not present as a key in the object `cat`.

Since you know that `col.name` must be a keyof the `Cat` interface, you can hint TypeScript as such:

```
// Tell TS that col.name must be a keyof the Cat interface
cat[col.name as keyof Cat]
```

Therefore, updating your code like this will cause TypeScript to recognize that `col.name` indeed returns a valid key in the `Cat` interface:

```
cats.map(cat => {
  cols.map(col => {
    console.log(`${col.title} - ${cat[col.name as keyof Cat]}`);
  });
});
```

[See proof-of-concept example on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJzMg3gKGcmAVygC5kBnMKUAczwIHsGATMy6kOgXxxwQZCVkCDOTIBBKFDgBPADzowAPmQBeZAG16ufPiKlkAcgBGUBgHcQhgDT09TVkZjByAC0P0ut-Dt36yhuauwJA2dowsAcYuCIQh5B74PAC6ANy8oJCwiCioDAA25Nj0IHAAthBsVLT0YCH5lRTVnDg8fAJC-IUSUrIKBeQq6lo%204aUVAfphush1YA0BAGLEwgUMxInIXtpj5Y2GMA7TunMLRotwAG7r1JARzJsp6XyiAHRlcAAOABQimKoqXxdcjvL6-ApqQHhfiCAoQV75Bg0b4AAwAJFguq9ThAuMgALTIDF-DRY8YoOBFADWEBkDBgaAwyS4KIAlOkkuzWuygA).

Pro-tip: let's say that you don't have an explicit interface `Cat` but only have the `cat` object, you can also do:

```
// Tell TS that col.name must be a keyof the typeof `cat` object
cat[col.name as keyof typeof cat]
```

---

An alternative way is to use `enum` for the properties in the `Cat` interface, so you don't have to manually cast it: since TypeScript can infer the type as such. This method is considerably more verbose at the expanse of not needed to manually cast the type of `col.name` ([see Playground example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=11&pln=29&pc=26#code/KYOwrgtgBAwghgFwAoCcD2AHYKEE8oDeAUFFAGICqASlALxQDkAZmCgwDQnkDy3AInUZM0aACYciAXyJEAliATYmcAMbBYiQlxYoAXFADOCFPIDm2kaP1GTIc9KIq0II1BWID+gIIoUcXAA88AgAfIIA2lzEpKQ6+gwARugA7iASMVDCYvFMsgYAFgxckpyk0TFxjMn5sorpFZbxCXkqYLUGRaTSALoA3DLyiijKarBoADYGWqQgcBDA+sGomNh4-aQIteMLhsZm-Q5OLghuE55QPn6BMGdh9JFlXDNzO0voWDi4AHSUVKUxmwQ23iZFYp3GaFYnSgJSiTygs3mi0Qyw+eB+vD4-w2Wx2DDIcAAbpCTIpMpZoT1+o4PF8IHAMAAKdwnWhhcpOSZ0hnMiZ0dnwo4GCbAL4Q0yMgAGABICJyvoDtpIoABaKCylnheWI4DdSSSgCU6xhRqkRqAA)):

```
// Declare an enum for properties in `Cat` interface
enum CatProperty {
  FUR = 'fur',
  FOOD = 'food',
}
```

Then, when defining an array for your `cols`, you will need to use enums:

```
const cols: Array<Cols> = [
  {
    name: CatProperty.FUR,
    title: 'Fur colour'
  }
];
```

This should result in TypeScript being able to recognize that `col.name` must be a value of `fur | food`, which all exists in the `Cat` interface, so no casting is needed:

```
cats.map(cat => {
  cols.map(col => {
    console.log(`${col.title} - ${cat[col.name]}`);
  });
});
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Thanks so much for the answer & taking the time to explain it so well :-) ....I'm pretty new to Typescript and the kindness of random strangers like you may just stop me pulling my hair out ;-)  You made my day!

Comment: @BaronVonKaneHoffen Glad to be able to help :)